# How can i add a new entry into table and change the sort order of other entries

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm creating a forum application and I have a table that stores the categories. This table has 3 columns:

```
Category_Id | Category_Name | CategoryOrder
```

I have a PHP script that adds a new category to the databse and it includes selecting the order in which the categories will display. So, for instance, if I have 5 categories stored in the database and I want to add a new one and make it the number one category in the `CategoryOrder` column, it means that the `CategoryOrder` of other categories will have to change.

If I only had one category in the table I would just update it to a new value and assign the `1` value to the new category. But what should I do if I have five rows. How do I change all of them to add `1` to their current value? I don't know if I'm making sense here.

Comment: Using `DML` statements...

Comment: You mean like using the UPDATE statement and stuff? My problem is really not about the statement to use but about how to change the numerical values of the CategoryOrder column of all the rows when a new category that takes the Order of an already existing one is entered

Answer (score 2):

I did this a few times. I couldn't find any code right now so I'll post only an algorithm (with maybe some pseudo code in it):

1. INSERTING a new value (simpler one):

   - update all the categories that have `CategoryOrder` bigger or the same as the newly inserted one:
     `UPDATE Categories SET CategoryOrder = CategoryOrder + 1 WHERE CategoryOrder >= $newCategory['order'];`
   - insert Your new Category
2. UPDATING an existing category:

   - check, whether the new order is bigger or smaller than it was (nothing has to be done if it is the same...)
   - if it is bigger, update all the categories that have `CategoryOrder` bigger than old order and smaller then new order and subtract 1:
     `UPDATE Categories SET CategoryOrder = CategoryOrder - 1 WHERE CategoryOrder > $category['old_order'] AND CategoryOrder <= $category['new_order'];` - by this You fill the gap
   - if it is smaller, do it similar to when it is bigger, but add 1 to those categories that have `CategoryOrder >= new_order` and `CategoryOrder < new_order`

This should be it.

**EDIT**: Explanation on the second case (updating):

Let's say we have these entries:

```
Category_Id | Category_Name | CategoryOrder
1           | name_1        | 1
2           | name_2        | 2
3           | name_3        | 3
4           | name_4        | 4
5           | name_5        | 5
```

And now we want to edit category with order `2` and change it to `4`. What we have to do is make the categories with order `3` and `4` go down by one:

```
Category_Id | Category_Name | CategoryOrder
1           | name_1        | 1
2           | name_2        | 2
3           | name_3        | 2
4           | name_4        | 3
5           | name_5        | 5
```

and finally update the desired category and it's order to `4`:

```
Category_Id | Category_Name | CategoryOrder
1           | name_1        | 1
3           | name_3        | 2
4           | name_4        | 3
2           | name_2        | 4
5           | name_5        | 5
```

**Is it clearer now?**

Now what if we want to change category with order `5` to become the first one? Update all the categories that have order >= `1` and `5` < and set the order to `+1`:

```
Category_Id | Category_Name | CategoryOrder
1           | name_1        | 2
3           | name_3        | 3
4           | name_4        | 4
2           | name_2        | 5
5           | name_5        | 5
```

and finally update the desired category:

```
Category_Id | Category_Name | CategoryOrder
5           | name_5        | 1
1           | name_1        | 2
3           | name_3        | 3
4           | name_4        | 4
2           | name_2        | 5
```

(note the categories being ordered by their order and id)

Comment: This looks more comprehensive and could solve all my problems. Though i'm still trying to understand the No 2.

Comment: I get it fully now. Let me test it.

Answer (score 0):

try to increment the CategoryOrder first

```
update categorytable set CategoryOrder = CategoryOrder + 1
```

then insert the new record with `CategoryOrder = 1`

Comment: This looks more like it, Let me try it out first.

Comment: This would be enough if and only he will set order to `1` for the newly inserted category. If he would like to insert a new category with order set to `3` while there are 5 other categories, Your query will disrupt the order...

Comment: I didn't mention the other part. I won't only be inserting  a category to replace the one at the top echelon. I could also want it ahead of the one currently at order no 3 or 4.

Comment: @Afam Then check my answer which solves all of the cases... Inserting and updating...